# Matlab reading dynamic url data

Tags: matlab, dynamic-url

I want to use MATLAB to read the data from a URL which is dynamically changing. Can I do this? Here is my code:

```
function reading(company, signal)
url1='https://finance.yahoo.com'; 
url2='market-overview'; 
url=strcat(url1,'company',url2,'signal'); 
name=strcat(company,signal);
urlwrite('url','name.h5');
```

I got this error:

> Either this URL could not be parsed or the protocol is not supported.

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: can give a example company and signal?

Comment: Hi, lakesh, this is just a example format. The idea is that I can input some part of the URL, then merging a valid url. then go to download the data.

Comment: @user2307344 we get the idea. We need an example that reproduces the error.

Comment: this might be not easy, I am not allowed for that...Sorry, I just want to know the way how to merge the url together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`url`, is a variable. `'url'`, is a string containing the letters `url`. You seem to be treating them as if they are interchangeable.

i.e.. when you do this:

```
url1='https://finance.yahoo.com'; 
url2='market-overview'; 
url=strcat(url1,'company',url2,'signal');
```

The output will always be the same regardless of the variables `company` and `signal`, because you are only passing strings, not variable names. You need:

```
% company and signal are names of variables you pass into your function
url=strcat(url1,company,url2,signal);
```

(You ought to be able to work out, then, what the issue is with your `urlwrite` command).

Comment: thanks nkjt, it works now with the strcat issue. urlwrite is that I want to read the data from this dynamic url I just created ans save it in a .h5 files.